# Stripping images from an .rtf by passing through textbox with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, textbox

In one part of my app users can copy a Word or rtf document and paste it into a textbox on a form, and on submitting the form any images and a lot of formatting are stripped out of the form field content.

I want to achieve the same result but by reading from the file direct rather than by a manual form submit i.e. strip out the hidden characters and image data and just leave text and linefeeds / carriage returns.

How can I achieve a similar thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to extract the text from Word documents, you could try POI. CF9 already includes a version that can handle most .doc or .docx files. (It does *not* handle .rtf files). For CF8, you will need to use the javaLoader to load a newer version.  [Reading Office documents with ColdFusion (2)](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/2/5/Reading-Office-documents-with-ColdFusion-2).

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog post that might assist: http://www.leavethatthingalone.com/blog/index.cfm/2005/6/11/Using-ColdFusion-to-convert-RTF-to-XHTML

This process converts the rtf file to xml, and then you can use ColdFusion's xml tags to read the converted file.

**Process**

1. download majix library as directed
2. extract lib folder and save to ColdFusion server
3. add the extracted location to the ColdFusion class path and restart the server
4. follow the code sample in the blog

Note that this library automatically creates the xml file. If your input file is mydoc.rtf your xml output file is mydoc.xml

Sample output created by this process:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<?xml:stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mydoc.xsl"?>
<!-- generated by Majix from c:\doc.rtf on Mon Jan 31 12:04:03 EST 2011 using template MyDoc -->
<!DOCTYPE mydoc PUBLIC "-//TetraSix//DTD mydoc v1.1//EN" "mydoc.dtd" [
<!NOTATION wmf PUBLIC "-/TetraSix/NOTATION Windows Metafile/EN" "wmf">
<!ENTITY g001 SYSTEM "images/doc_001.wmf" NDATA wmf>
]>
<mydoc>


<p>This is my rtf document</p>

<p></p>

<p><graphic url='images/doc_001.wmf'/></p>

<p></p>

<p></p>
</mydoc>
```

I created my own test bed using the linked library with ColdFusion 9 without any problems.

Note that I skipped the second `rereplacenocase` from the blog post as it resulted in a malfored xml document.

Once you have your xml file you can read it like so:

```
<cffile action="read" file="c:\doc.xml" variable="xmldoc">
<cfdump var="#xmlparse(xmldoc)#" />
```

Resulting in this xml object:

[image]

Comment: One thing that bothered me about Majix was its use of System.exit(..) in several places. I discovered the hard that can shut down your jvm. So if you do use it, I would recommend recompiling your own version (without any System.exit calls) before using it on a server.